# Maximum Number of columns in MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I'm fairly new to MySQL. I have a few questions:

1) How many (maximum) no. of columns can be created in a MySQL Table.

2) How many (maximum) no. of tables can be created in a MySQL database.

Answer (score 12):

- 1- Approximately 4,096 columns per table.
- 2-mySQL has [no limit on the number of databases.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/database-count-limit.html) The underlying file system may have a limit on the number of tables. Individual storage engines may impose engine-specific constraints. InnoDB permits up to 4 billion tables.

Comment: This is a bit misleading. Nowadays the default storage engine is innodb and that has a maximum number of columns of 1000.

Answer (score 9):

You can find precise information here :

- [Maximum no. of columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/column-count-limit.html)
- [Maximum no. of tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/database-count-limit.html)

In a nutshell:

- 4096 columns per table, 1017 with InnoDB
- No limit on the number of tables, 4 billion with InnoDB