# ERROR 1117 (HY000): Too many columns

Tags: join, mysql-workbench, mysql

Hi i was trying to join two tables in MySQL and came up with the error 1117: too many columns,I have around 800 columns in both the table ...Is there any way to resolve this issue because I need it as a single table,because i need it for a analytial purpose ....
  I checked on web and found that MySQL is incapable to handle such a big data,but it could hold almost around 4000 columns ....

```
     create table full_join
 select
 a.Period,
 a.market,
 Det_CS_GRP,
 Dove_CS_GRP,
 Vivel_CS_GRP,
 Venus_CS_GRP,
 Cin_CS_GRP,
 Chand_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_CS_GRP,
 Fiama_CS_GRP,
 JB_CS_GRP,
 Rex_CS_GRP,
 Lux_CS_GRP,
 LB_CS_GRP,
 Pears_CS_GRP,
 EMPTY_CS_GRP,
 HAMAM_CS_GRP,
 LIRIL_CS_GRP,
 Margo_CS_GRP,
 Breeze_CS_GRP,
 GD_CS_GRP,
 Nima_CS_GRP,
 SAVLON_CS_GRP,
 SUPERIA_CS_GRP,
 San_white_CS_GRP,
 Mysore_CS_GRP,
 Med_CS_GRP,
 NATURE_POWER_CS_GRP,
 EMAMI_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_CS_GRP,
 CUTICURA_CS_GRP,
 Park_Avn_CS_GRP,
 K_P_NAMBOOD_CS_GRP,
 San_others_CS_GRP,
 Dyna_CS_GRP,
 HIMALAYA_NEEM_CS_GRP,
 MOTI_CS_GRP,
 Doy_CS_GRP,
 Yardley_ENG_LAVEN_CS_GRP,
 Jo_CS_GRP,
 AXE_CS_GRP,
 FAIR_BEAT_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Genre1_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Genre2_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Genre3_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Genre4_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Genre5_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Genre6_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Genre7_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Genre8_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Genre9_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Genre10_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Genre11_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Genre12_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Genre13_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Genre14_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Genre15_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Genre16_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Genre17_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Genre18_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Genre19_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Genre20_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Genre21_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Genre22_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Genre23_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Genre24_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Genre25_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Genre26_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Genre27_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Genre28_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Genre29_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Genre30_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Genre31_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Genre32_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Genre33_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Genre34_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Genre35_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Genre36_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Genre37_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Genre38_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Genre39_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Genre40_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Genre41_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Genre42_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Genre43_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Genre1_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Genre2_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Genre3_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Genre4_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Genre5_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Genre6_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Genre7_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Genre8_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Genre9_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Genre10_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Genre11_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Genre12_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Genre13_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Genre14_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Genre15_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Genre16_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Genre17_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Genre18_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Genre19_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Genre20_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Genre21_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Genre22_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Genre23_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Genre24_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Genre25_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Genre26_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Genre27_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Genre28_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Genre29_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Genre30_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Genre31_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Genre32_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Genre33_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Genre34_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Genre35_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Genre36_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Genre37_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Genre38_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Genre39_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Genre40_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Genre41_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Genre42_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Genre43_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Genre44_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Genre45_CS_GRP,
 San_others_Genre1_CS_GRP,
 San_others_Genre2_CS_GRP,
 San_others_Genre3_CS_GRP,
 San_others_Genre4_CS_GRP,
 San_others_Genre5_CS_GRP,
 San_others_Genre6_CS_GRP,
 San_others_Genre7_CS_GRP,
 San_others_Genre8_CS_GRP,
 San_others_Genre9_CS_GRP,
 San_others_Genre10_CS_GRP,
 San_others_Genre11_CS_GRP,
 San_others_Genre12_CS_GRP,
 San_others_Genre13_CS_GRP,
 San_others_Genre14_CS_GRP,
 San_others_Genre15_CS_GRP,
 San_others_Genre16_CS_GRP,
 San_others_Genre17_CS_GRP,
 San_others_Genre18_CS_GRP,
 San_others_Genre19_CS_GRP,
 San_others_Genre20_CS_GRP,
 San_others_Genre21_CS_GRP,
 San_others_Genre22_CS_GRP,
 San_others_Genre23_CS_GRP,
 San_others_Genre24_CS_GRP,
 San_others_Genre25_CS_GRP,
 San_others_Genre26_CS_GRP,
 San_others_Genre27_CS_GRP,
 San_others_Genre28_CS_GRP,
 San_others_Genre29_CS_GRP,
 San_others_Genre30_CS_GRP,
 San_others_Genre31_CS_GRP,
 San_others_Genre32_CS_GRP,
 San_others_Genre33_CS_GRP,
 San_others_Genre34_CS_GRP,
 San_others_Genre35_CS_GRP,
 San_others_Genre36_CS_GRP,
 San_white_Genre1_CS_GRP,
 San_white_Genre2_CS_GRP,
 San_white_Genre3_CS_GRP,
 San_white_Genre4_CS_GRP,
 San_white_Genre5_CS_GRP,
 San_white_Genre6_CS_GRP,
 San_white_Genre7_CS_GRP,
 San_white_Genre8_CS_GRP,
 San_white_Genre9_CS_GRP,
 San_white_Genre10_CS_GRP,
 San_white_Genre11_CS_GRP,
 San_white_Genre12_CS_GRP,
 San_white_Genre13_CS_GRP,
 San_white_Genre14_CS_GRP,
 San_white_Genre15_CS_GRP,
 San_white_Genre16_CS_GRP,
 San_white_Genre17_CS_GRP,
 San_white_Genre18_CS_GRP,
 San_white_Genre19_CS_GRP,
 San_white_Genre20_CS_GRP,
 San_white_Genre21_CS_GRP,
 San_white_Genre22_CS_GRP,
 San_white_Genre23_CS_GRP,
 San_white_Genre24_CS_GRP,
 San_white_Genre25_CS_GRP,
 San_white_Genre26_CS_GRP,
 San_white_Genre27_CS_GRP,
 San_white_Genre28_CS_GRP,
 San_white_Genre29_CS_GRP,
 San_white_Genre30_CS_GRP,
 San_white_Genre31_CS_GRP,
 San_white_Genre32_CS_GRP,
 San_white_Genre33_CS_GRP,
 San_white_Genre34_CS_GRP,
 San_white_Genre35_CS_GRP,
 San_white_Genre36_CS_GRP,
 San_white_Genre37_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Creative1_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Creative10_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Creative11_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Creative12_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Creative13_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Creative14_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Creative15_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Creative16_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Creative17_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Creative18_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Creative19_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Creative2_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Creative20_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Creative21_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Creative3_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Creative4_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Creative5_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Creative6_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Creative7_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Creative8_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Creative9_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative1_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative10_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative11_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative12_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative13_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative14_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative15_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative16_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative17_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative18_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative19_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative2_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative20_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative21_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative22_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative23_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative24_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative25_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative26_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative27_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative28_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative29_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative3_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative30_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative31_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative32_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative33_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative34_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative35_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative36_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative37_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative38_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative39_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative4_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative40_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative41_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative42_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative43_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative44_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative45_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative46_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative47_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative48_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative49_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative5_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative50_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative51_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative52_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative53_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative54_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative55_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative56_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative57_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative58_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative59_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative6_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative60_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative61_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative62_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative63_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative64_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative7_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative8_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Creative9_CS_GRP,
 San_Others_Creative1_CS_GRP,
 San_Others_Creative2_CS_GRP,
 San_Others_Creative3_CS_GRP,
 San_Others_Creative4_CS_GRP,
 San_Others_Creative5_CS_GRP,
 San_Others_Creative6_CS_GRP,
 San_White_Creative1_CS_GRP,
 San_White_Creative2_CS_GRP,
 San_White_Creative3_CS_GRP,
 San_White_Creative4_CS_GRP,
 San_White_Creative5_CS_GRP,
 San_White_Creative6_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_30SEC_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_15SEC_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_10SEC_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_5SEC_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_45SEC_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_20SEC_CS_GRP,
 San_white_30SEC_CS_GRP,
 San_white_20SEC_CS_GRP,
 San_white_15SEC_CS_GRP,
 San_white_5SEC_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_25SEC_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_20SEC_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_25SEC_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_40SEC_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_30SEC_CS_GRP,
 San_white_10SEC_CS_GRP,
 San_others_40SEC_CS_GRP,
 San_others_5SEC_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_5SEC_CS_GRP,
 San_others_15SEC_CS_GRP,
 San_others_35SEC_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_10SEC_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_15SEC_CS_GRP,
 San_white_40SEC_CS_GRP,
 San_white_25SEC_CS_GRP,
 San_others_20SEC_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_35SEC_CS_GRP,
 San_others_10SEC_CS_GRP,
 San_others_30SEC_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_35SEC_CS_GRP,
 EMAMI_NPT_CS_GRP,
 EMAMI_PT_CS_GRP,
 EMPTY_PT_CS_GRP,
 EMPTY_NPT_CS_GRP,
 Det_NPT_CS_GRP,
 Det_PT_CS_GRP,
 Lux_PT_CS_GRP,
 Lux_NPT_CS_GRP,
 LB_PT_CS_GRP,
 LB_NPT_CS_GRP,
 Dove_NPT_CS_GRP,
 Vivel_NPT_CS_GRP,
 Vivel_PT_CS_GRP,
 Pears_NPT_CS_GRP,
 Pears_PT_CS_GRP,
 Dove_PT_CS_GRP,
 LIRIL_NPT_CS_GRP,
 LIRIL_PT_CS_GRP,
 SUPERIA_NPT_CS_GRP,
 SUPERIA_PT_CS_GRP,
 Margo_NPT_CS_GRP,
 Margo_PT_CS_GRP,
 Cin_NPT_CS_GRP,
 Cin_PT_CS_GRP,
 Venus_NPT_CS_GRP,
 Venus_PT_CS_GRP,
 Chand_PT_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_PT_CS_GRP,
 Chand_NPT_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_NPT_CS_GRP,
 Fiama_PT_CS_GRP,
 Rex_NPT_CS_GRP,
 Fiama_NPT_CS_GRP,
 JB_NPT_CS_GRP,
 JB_PT_CS_GRP,
 Rex_PT_CS_GRP,
 HAMAM_NPT_CS_GRP,
 HAMAM_PT_CS_GRP,
 Breeze_NPT_CS_GRP,
 Breeze_PT_CS_GRP,
 GD_NPT_CS_GRP,
 GD_PT_CS_GRP,
 Nima_PT_CS_GRP,
 Mysore_NPT_CS_GRP,
 SAVLON_NPT_CS_GRP,
 San_white_PT_CS_GRP,
 SAVLON_PT_CS_GRP,
 Nima_NPT_CS_GRP,
 San_white_NPT_CS_GRP,
 Mysore_PT_CS_GRP,
 Med_PT_CS_GRP,
 Med_NPT_CS_GRP,
 NATURE_POWER_NPT_CS_GRP,
 NATURE_POWER_PT_CS_GRP,
 Park_Avn_NPT_CS_GRP,
 Park_Avn_PT_CS_GRP,
 MOTI_NPT_CS_GRP,
 MOTI_PT_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_NPT_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_PT_CS_GRP,
 CUTICURA_PT_CS_GRP,
 CUTICURA_NPT_CS_GRP,
 K_P_NAMBOOD_PT_CS_GRP,
 San_others_NPT_CS_GRP,
 San_others_PT_CS_GRP,
 K_P_NAMBOOD_NPT_CS_GRP,
 Dyna_PT_CS_GRP,
 Dyna_NPT_CS_GRP,
 HIMALAYA_NEEM_NPT_CS_GRP,
 HIMALAYA_NEEM_PT_CS_GRP,
 Doy_NPT_CS_GRP,
 Doy_PT_CS_GRP,
 Yardley_ENG_LAVEN_NPT_CS_GRP,
 Yardley_ENG_LAVEN_PT_CS_GRP,
 Jo_NPT_CS_GRP,
 Jo_PT_CS_GRP,
 AXE_NPT_CS_GRP,
 AXE_PT_CS_GRP,
 FAIR_BEAT_NPT_CS_GRP,
 FAIR_BEAT_PT_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_National_CS_GRP,
 San_Gly_Regional_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_National_CS_GRP,
 San_Orange_Regional_CS_GRP,
 San_others_National_CS_GRP,
 San_others_Regional_CS_GRP,
 San_white_National_CS_GRP,
 San_white_Regional_CS_GRP,
 Cin_Vol_Tons,
 Cin_Val_Mns,
 Cin_Ms_Vol,
 Cin_Ms_Val,
 Cin_Ndist,
 Cin_Wtd_Val,
 Cin_Sah_Val,
 Cin_Nos,
 Dett_Vol_Tons,
 Dett_Val_Mns,
 Dett_Ms_Vol,
 Dett_Ms_Val,
 Dett_Ndist,
 Dett_Wtd_Val,
 Dett_Sah_Val,
 Dett_Nos,
 Dove_Vol_Tons,
 Dove_Val_Mns,
 Dove_Ms_Vol,
 Dove_Ms_Val,
 Dove_Ndist,
 Dove_Wtd_Val,
 Dove_Sah_Val,
 Dove_Nos,
 Gd_Vol_Tons,
 Gd_Val_Mns,
 Gd_Ms_Vol,
 Gd_Ms_Val,
 Gd_Ndist,
 Gd_Wtd_Val,
 Gd_Sah_Val,
 Gd_Nos,
 Hamam_Vol_Tons,
 Hamam_Val_Mns,
 Hamam_Ms_Vol,
 Hamam_Ms_Val,
 Hamam_Ndist,
 Hamam_Wtd_Val,
 Hamam_Sah_Val,
 Hamam_Nos,
 Jb_Vol_Tons,
 Jb_Val_Mns,
 Jb_Ms_Vol,
 Jb_Ms_Val,
 Jb_Ndist,
 Jb_Wtd_Val,
 Jb_Sah_Val,
 Jb_Nos,
 Lb_Vol_Tons,
 Lb_Val_Mns,
 Lb_Ms_Vol,
 Lb_Ms_Val,
 Lb_Ndist,
 Lb_Wtd_Val,
 Lb_Sah_Val,
 Lb_Nos,
 Liril_Vol_Tons,
 Liril_Val_Mns,
 Liril_Ms_Vol,
 Liril_Ms_Val,
 Liril_Ndist,
 Liril_Wtd_Val,
 Liril_Sah_Val,
 Liril_Nos,
 Lux_Vol_Tons,
 Lux_Val_Mns,
 Lux_Ms_Vol,
 Lux_Ms_Val,
 Lux_Ndist,
 Lux_Wtd_Val,
 Lux_Sah_Val,
 Lux_Nos,
 Med_Vol_Tons,
 Med_Val_Mns,
 Med_Ms_Vol,
 Med_Ms_Val,
 Med_Ndist,
 Med_Wtd_Val,
 Med_Sah_Val,
 Med_Nos,
 Pears_Vol_Tons,
 Pears_Val_Mns,
 Pears_Ms_Vol,
 Pears_Ms_Val,
 Pears_Ndist,
 Pears_Wtd_Val,
 Pears_Sah_Val,
 Pears_Nos,
 Rex_Vol_Tons,
 Rex_Val_Mns,
 Rex_Ms_Vol,
 Rex_Ms_Val,
 Rex_Ndist,
 Rex_Wtd_Val,
 Rex_Sah_Val,
 Rex_Nos,
 San_Gly_Vol_Tons,
 San_Gly_Val_Mns,
 San_Gly_Ms_Vol,
 San_Gly_Ms_Val,
 San_Gly_Ndist,
 San_Gly_Wtd_Val,
 San_Gly_Sah_Val,
 San_Gly_Nos,
 San_Orange_Vol_Tons,
 San_Orange_Val_Mns,
 San_Orange_Ms_Vol,
 San_Orange_Ms_Val,
 San_Orange_Ndist,
 San_Orange_Wtd_Val,
 San_Orange_Sah_Val,
 San_Orange_Nos,
 San_Other_Vol_Tons,
 San_Other_Val_Mns,
 San_Other_Ms_Vol,
 San_Other_Ms_Val,
 San_Other_Ndist,
 San_Other_Wtd_Val,
 San_Other_Sah_Val,
 San_Other_Nos,
 San_Others_Vol_Tons,
 San_Others_Val_Mns,
 San_Others_Ms_Vol,
 San_Others_Ms_Val,
 San_Others_Ndist,
 San_Others_Wtd_Val,
 San_Others_Sah_Val,
 San_Others_Nos,
 San_Total_Vol_Tons,
 San_Total_Val_Mns,
 San_Total_Ms_Vol,
 San_Total_Ms_Val,
 San_Total_Ndist,
 San_Total_Wtd_Val,
 San_Total_Sah_Val,
 San_Total_Nos,
 San_White_Vol_Tons,
 San_White_Val_Mns,
 San_White_Ms_Vol,
 San_White_Ms_Val,
 San_White_Ndist,
 San_White_Wtd_Val,
 San_White_Sah_Val,
 San_White_Nos,
 Sav_Vol_Tons,
 Sav_Val_Mns,
 Sav_Ms_Vol,
 Sav_Ms_Val,
 Sav_Ndist,
 Sav_Wtd_Val,
 Sav_Sah_Val,
 Sav_Nos,
 Vivel_Vol_Tons,
 Vivel_Val_Mns,
 Vivel_Ms_Vol,
 Vivel_Ms_Val,
 Vivel_Ndist,
 Vivel_Wtd_Val,
 Vivel_Sah_Val,
 Vivel_Nos,
Breeze_Creative1_NCS_GRP,
Breeze_Creative2_NCS_GRP,
Breeze_Creative3_NCS_GRP,
Breeze_Creative4_NCS_GRP,
Breeze_Creative5_NCS_GRP,
Breeze_Creative6_NCS_GRP,
Chand_Creative1_NCS_GRP,
Chand_Creative2_NCS_GRP,
Chand_Creative3_NCS_GRP,
Chand_Creative4_NCS_GRP,
Chand_Creative5_NCS_GRP,
Chand_Creative6_NCS_GRP,
Chand_Creative7_NCS_GRP,
Chand_Creative8_NCS_GRP,
Chand_Creative9_NCS_GRP,
Chand_Creative10_NCS_GRP,
Chand_Creative11_NCS_GRP,
Chand_Creative12_NCS_GRP,
Chand_Creative13_NCS_GRP,
Chand_Creative14_NCS_GRP,
Chand_Creative15_NCS_GRP,
Chand_Creative16_NCS_GRP,
Chand_Creative17_NCS_GRP,
Chand_Creative18_NCS_GRP,
Chand_Creative19_NCS_GRP,
Chand_Creative20_NCS_GRP,
Chand_Creative21_NCS_GRP,
Chand_Creative22_NCS_GRP,
Chand_Creative23_NCS_GRP,
Chand_Creative24_NCS_GRP,
Chand_Creative25_NCS_GRP,
Chand_Creative26_NCS_GRP,
Chand_Creative27_NCS_GRP,
Chand_Creative28_NCS_GRP,
Chand_Creative29_NCS_GRP,
Chand_Creative30_NCS_GRP,
Chand_Creative31_NCS_GRP,
Chand_Creative32_NCS_GRP,
Chand_Creative33_NCS_GRP,
Cin_Creative1_NCS_GRP,
Cin_Creative2_NCS_GRP,
Cin_Creative3_NCS_GRP,
Cin_Creative4_NCS_GRP,
Cin_Creative5_NCS_GRP,
Cin_Creative6_NCS_GRP,
Cin_Creative7_NCS_GRP,
Cin_Creative8_NCS_GRP,
Cin_Creative9_NCS_GRP,
Cin_Creative10_NCS_GRP,
Cin_Creative11_NCS_GRP,
Cin_Creative12_NCS_GRP,
Cin_Creative13_NCS_GRP,
Cin_Creative14_NCS_GRP,
Cin_Creative15_NCS_GRP,
Cin_Creative16_NCS_GRP,
Cin_Creative17_NCS_GRP,
Cin_Creative18_NCS_GRP,
Cin_Creative19_NCS_GRP,
Cin_Creative20_NCS_GRP,
Cin_Creative21_NCS_GRP,
Cin_Creative22_NCS_GRP,
Cin_Creative23_NCS_GRP,
Cin_Creative24_NCS_GRP,
Cin_Creative25_NCS_GRP,
Cin_Creative26_NCS_GRP,
Cin_Creative27_NCS_GRP,
Det_Creative1_NCS_GRP,
Det_Creative2_NCS_GRP,
Det_Creative3_NCS_GRP,
Det_Creative4_NCS_GRP,
Det_Creative5_NCS_GRP,
Det_Creative6_NCS_GRP,
Det_Creative7_NCS_GRP,
Det_Creative8_NCS_GRP,
Det_Creative9_NCS_GRP,
Det_Creative10_NCS_GRP,
Det_Creative11_NCS_GRP,
Det_Creative12_NCS_GRP,
Det_Creative13_NCS_GRP,
Det_Creative14_NCS_GRP,
Det_Creative15_NCS_GRP,
Det_Creative16_NCS_GRP,
Det_Creative17_NCS_GRP,
Det_Creative18_NCS_GRP,
Det_Creative19_NCS_GRP,
Det_Creative20_NCS_GRP,
Det_Creative21_NCS_GRP,
Det_Creative22_NCS_GRP,
Det_Creative23_NCS_GRP,
Det_Creative24_NCS_GRP,
Det_Creative25_NCS_GRP,
Det_Creative26_NCS_GRP,
Det_Creative27_NCS_GRP,
Det_Creative28_NCS_GRP,
Det_Creative29_NCS_GRP,
Det_Creative30_NCS_GRP,
Det_Creative31_NCS_GRP,
Det_Creative32_NCS_GRP,
Det_Creative33_NCS_GRP,
Det_Creative34_NCS_GRP,
Det_Creative35_NCS_GRP,
Det_Creative36_NCS_GRP,
Det_Creative37_NCS_GRP,
Det_Creative38_NCS_GRP,
Det_Creative39_NCS_GRP,
Det_Creative40_NCS_GRP,
Det_Creative41_NCS_GRP,
Det_Creative42_NCS_GRP,
Det_Creative43_NCS_GRP,
Det_Creative44_NCS_GRP,
Det_Creative45_NCS_GRP,
Det_Creative46_NCS_GRP,
Det_Creative47_NCS_GRP,
Det_Creative48_NCS_GRP,
Det_Creative49_NCS_GRP,
Det_Creative50_NCS_GRP,
Det_Creative51_NCS_GRP,
Det_Creative52_NCS_GRP,
Dove_Creative1_NCS_GRP,
Dove_Creative2_NCS_GRP,
Dove_Creative3_NCS_GRP,
Dove_Creative4_NCS_GRP,
Dove_Creative5_NCS_GRP,
Dove_Creative6_NCS_GRP,
Dove_Creative7_NCS_GRP,
Dove_Creative8_NCS_GRP,
Dove_Creative9_NCS_GRP,
Dove_Creative10_NCS_GRP,
Dove_Creative11_NCS_GRP,
Dove_Creative12_NCS_GRP,
Dove_Creative13_NCS_GRP,
Dove_Creative14_NCS_GRP,
Dove_Creative15_NCS_GRP,
Dove_Creative16_NCS_GRP,
Dove_Creative17_NCS_GRP,
Dove_Creative18_NCS_GRP,
Dove_Creative19_NCS_GRP,
Dove_Creative20_NCS_GRP,
Dove_Creative21_NCS_GRP,
Dove_Creative22_NCS_GRP,
Dove_Creative23_NCS_GRP,
Dove_Creative24_NCS_GRP,
Dove_Creative25_NCS_GRP,
Dove_Creative26_NCS_GRP,
Dove_Creative27_NCS_GRP,
Dove_Creative28_NCS_GRP,
Dove_Creative29_NCS_GRP,
Dove_Creative30_NCS_GRP,
Dove_Creative31_NCS_GRP,
Dove_Creative32_NCS_GRP,
Dove_Creative33_NCS_GRP,
Dove_Creative34_NCS_GRP,
Gd_Creative1_NCS_GRP,
Gd_Creative2_NCS_GRP,
Gd_Creative3_NCS_GRP,
Gd_Creative4_NCS_GRP,
Gd_Creative5_NCS_GRP,
Gd_Creative6_NCS_GRP,
Gd_Creative7_NCS_GRP,
Gd_Creative8_NCS_GRP,
Gd_Creative9_NCS_GRP,
Gd_Creative10_NCS_GRP,
Gd_Creative11_NCS_GRP,
Gd_Creative12_NCS_GRP,
Gd_Creative13_NCS_GRP,
Gd_Creative14_NCS_GRP,
Gd_Creative15_NCS_GRP,
Gd_Creative16_NCS_GRP,
Gd_Creative17_NCS_GRP,
Gd_Creative18_NCS_GRP,
Gd_Creative19_NCS_GRP,
Hamam_Creative1_NCS_GRP,
Hamam_Creative2_NCS_GRP,
Hamam_Creative3_NCS_GRP,
Hamam_Creative4_NCS_GRP,
Hamam_Creative5_NCS_GRP,
Hamam_Creative6_NCS_GRP,
Hamam_Creative7_NCS_GRP,
Hamam_Creative8_NCS_GRP,
Hamam_Creative9_NCS_GRP,
Hamam_Creative10_NCS_GRP,
Hamam_Creative11_NCS_GRP,
Hamam_Creative12_NCS_GRP,
Hamam_Creative13_NCS_GRP,
Hamam_Creative14_NCS_GRP,
Hamam_Creative15_NCS_GRP,
Hamam_Creative16_NCS_GRP,
Hamam_Creative17_NCS_GRP,
Hamam_Creative18_NCS_GRP,
Lb_Creative1_NCS_GRP,
Lb_Creative2_NCS_GRP,
Lb_Creative3_NCS_GRP,
Lb_Creative4_NCS_GRP,
Lb_Creative5_NCS_GRP,
Lb_Creative6_NCS_GRP,
Lb_Creative7_NCS_GRP,
Lb_Creative8_NCS_GRP,
Lb_Creative9_NCS_GRP,
Lb_Creative10_NCS_GRP,
Lb_Creative11_NCS_GRP,
Lb_Creative12_NCS_GRP,
Lb_Creative13_NCS_GRP,
Lb_Creative14_NCS_GRP,
Lb_Creative15_NCS_GRP,
Lb_Creative16_NCS_GRP,
Lb_Creative17_NCS_GRP,
Lb_Creative18_NCS_GRP,
Lb_Creative19_NCS_GRP,
Lb_Creative20_NCS_GRP,
Lb_Creative21_NCS_GRP,
Lb_Creative22_NCS_GRP,
Lb_Creative23_NCS_GRP,
Lb_Creative24_NCS_GRP,
Lb_Creative25_NCS_GRP,
Lb_Creative26_NCS_GRP,
Lb_Creative27_NCS_GRP,
Lb_Creative28_NCS_GRP,
Lb_Creative29_NCS_GRP,
Lb_Creative30_NCS_GRP,
Lb_Creative31_NCS_GRP,
Lb_Creative32_NCS_GRP,
Lb_Creative33_NCS_GRP,
Lb_Creative34_NCS_GRP,
Lb_Creative35_NCS_GRP,
Lb_Creative36_NCS_GRP,
Lb_Creative37_NCS_GRP,
Lb_Creative38_NCS_GRP,
Lb_Creative39_NCS_GRP,
Lb_Creative40_NCS_GRP,
Lb_Creative41_NCS_GRP,
Med_Creative1_NCS_GRP,
Med_Creative2_NCS_GRP,
Med_Creative3_NCS_GRP,
Med_Creative4_NCS_GRP,
Med_Creative5_NCS_GRP,
Med_Creative6_NCS_GRP,
Med_Creative7_NCS_GRP,
Med_Creative8_NCS_GRP,
Med_Creative9_NCS_GRP,
Med_Creative10_NCS_GRP,
Med_Creative11_NCS_GRP,
Med_Creative12_NCS_GRP,
Med_Creative13_NCS_GRP,
Med_Creative14_NCS_GRP,
Med_Creative15_NCS_GRP,
Med_Creative16_NCS_GRP,
Med_Creative17_NCS_GRP,
Med_Creative18_NCS_GRP,
Med_Creative19_NCS_GRP,
Med_Creative20_NCS_GRP,
Med_Creative21_NCS_GRP,
San_Gly_Creative1_NCS_GRP,
San_Gly_Creative2_NCS_GRP,
San_Gly_Creative3_NCS_GRP,
San_Gly_Creative4_NCS_GRP,
San_Gly_Creative5_NCS_GRP,
San_Gly_Creative6_NCS_GRP,
San_Gly_Creative7_NCS_GRP,
San_Gly_Creative8_NCS_GRP,
San_Gly_Creative9_NCS_GRP,
San_Gly_Creative10_NCS_GRP,
San_Gly_Creative11_NCS_GRP,
San_Gly_Creative12_NCS_GRP,
San_Gly_Creative13_NCS_GRP,
San_Gly_Creative14_NCS_GRP,
San_Gly_Creative15_NCS_GRP,
San_Gly_Creative16_NCS_GRP,
San_Gly_Creative17_NCS_GRP,
San_Gly_Creative18_NCS_GRP,
San_Gly_Creative19_NCS_GRP,
San_Gly_Creative20_NCS_GRP,
San_Gly_Creative21_NCS_GRP,
San_Gly_Creative22_NCS_GRP,
San_Gly_Creative23_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative1_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative2_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative3_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative4_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative5_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative6_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative7_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative8_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative9_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative10_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative11_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative12_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative13_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative14_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative15_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative16_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative17_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative18_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative19_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative20_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative21_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative22_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative23_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative24_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative25_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative26_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative27_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative28_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative29_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative30_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative31_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative32_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative33_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative34_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative35_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative36_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative37_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative38_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative39_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative40_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative41_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative42_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative43_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative44_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative45_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative46_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative47_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative48_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative49_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative50_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative51_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative52_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative53_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative54_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative55_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative56_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative57_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative58_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative59_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative60_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative61_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative62_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative63_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative64_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative65_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative66_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative67_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative68_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative69_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative70_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative71_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative72_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative73_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Creative74_NCS_GRP,
San_Others_Creative1_NCS_GRP,
San_Others_Creative2_NCS_GRP,
San_Others_Creative3_NCS_GRP,
San_Others_Creative4_NCS_GRP,
San_Others_Creative5_NCS_GRP,
San_Others_Creative6_NCS_GRP,
San_White_Creative1_NCS_GRP,
San_White_Creative2_NCS_GRP,
San_White_Creative3_NCS_GRP,
San_White_Creative4_NCS_GRP,
San_White_Creative5_NCS_GRP,
San_White_Creative6_NCS_GRP,
Vivel_Creative1_NCS_GRP,
Vivel_Creative2_NCS_GRP,
Vivel_Creative3_NCS_GRP,
Vivel_Creative4_NCS_GRP,
Vivel_Creative5_NCS_GRP,
Vivel_Creative6_NCS_GRP,
Vivel_Creative7_NCS_GRP,
San_Others_Genre13_NCS_GRP,
San_Others_Genre14_NCS_GRP,
San_Others_Genre15_NCS_GRP,
San_Others_Genre16_NCS_GRP,
San_Others_Genre17_NCS_GRP,
San_Others_Genre18_NCS_GRP,
San_Others_Genre19_NCS_GRP,
San_Others_Genre20_NCS_GRP,
San_Others_Genre21_NCS_GRP,
San_Others_Genre22_NCS_GRP,
San_Others_Genre23_NCS_GRP,
San_Others_Genre24_NCS_GRP,
San_Others_Genre25_NCS_GRP,
San_Others_Genre26_NCS_GRP,
San_Others_Genre27_NCS_GRP,
San_Others_Genre28_NCS_GRP,
San_Others_Genre29_NCS_GRP,
San_Others_Genre30_NCS_GRP,
San_Others_Genre31_NCS_GRP,
San_Others_Genre32_NCS_GRP,
San_Others_Genre33_NCS_GRP,
San_Others_Genre34_NCS_GRP,
San_Others_Genre35_NCS_GRP,
San_Others_Genre36_NCS_GRP,
San_white_Genre1_NCS_GRP,
San_white_Genre2_NCS_GRP,
San_white_Genre3_NCS_GRP,
San_white_Genre4_NCS_GRP,
San_white_Genre5_NCS_GRP,
San_white_Genre6_NCS_GRP,
San_white_Genre7_NCS_GRP,
San_white_Genre8_NCS_GRP,
San_white_Genre9_NCS_GRP,
San_white_Genre10_NCS_GRP,
San_white_Genre11_NCS_GRP,
San_white_Genre12_NCS_GRP,
San_white_Genre13_NCS_GRP,
San_white_Genre14_NCS_GRP,
San_white_Genre15_NCS_GRP,
San_white_Genre16_NCS_GRP,
San_white_Genre17_NCS_GRP,
San_white_Genre18_NCS_GRP,
San_white_Genre19_NCS_GRP,
San_white_Genre20_NCS_GRP,
San_white_Genre21_NCS_GRP,
San_white_Genre22_NCS_GRP,
San_white_Genre23_NCS_GRP,
San_white_Genre24_NCS_GRP,
San_white_Genre25_NCS_GRP,
San_white_Genre26_NCS_GRP,
San_white_Genre27_NCS_GRP,
San_white_Genre28_NCS_GRP,
San_white_Genre29_NCS_GRP,
San_white_Genre30_NCS_GRP,
San_white_Genre31_NCS_GRP,
San_white_Genre32_NCS_GRP,
San_white_Genre33_NCS_GRP,
San_white_Genre34_NCS_GRP,
San_white_Genre35_NCS_GRP,
San_white_Genre36_NCS_GRP,
San_white_Genre37_NCS_GRP,
San_white_Genre38_NCS_GRP,
San_white_Genre39_NCS_GRP,
San_white_Genre40_NCS_GRP,
JB_NCS_GRP,
Breeze_NCS_GRP,
Lux_NCS_GRP,
LB_NCS_GRP,
Rex_NCS_GRP,
Det_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_NCS_GRP,
SUPERIA_NCS_GRP,
Pears_NCS_GRP,
Chand_NCS_GRP,
Vivel_NCS_GRP,
Venus_NCS_GRP,
Dove_NCS_GRP,
San_white_NCS_GRP,
SAVLON_NCS_GRP,
Mysore_NCS_GRP,
GD_NCS_GRP,
Nima_NCS_GRP,
LIRIL_NCS_GRP,
San_Gly_NCS_GRP,
MOTI_NCS_GRP,
San_others_NCS_GRP,
Dyna_NCS_GRP,
Cin_NCS_GRP,
HAMAM_NCS_GRP,
HIMALAYA_NEEM_NCS_GRP,
Med_NCS_GRP,
Margo_NCS_GRP,
JB_Regional_NCS_GRP,
Breeze_Regional_NCS_GRP,
Lux_Regional_NCS_GRP,
LB_Regional_NCS_GRP,
Rex_Regional_NCS_GRP,
LB_National_NCS_GRP,
Lux_National_NCS_GRP,
Breeze_National_NCS_GRP,
Det_National_NCS_GRP,
JB_National_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_National_NCS_GRP,
SUPERIA_Regional_NCS_GRP,
Pears_Regional_NCS_GRP,
San_Orange_Regional_NCS_GRP,
Chand_Regional_NCS_GRP,
Vivel_Regional_NCS_GRP,
Venus_National_NCS_GRP,
Dove_Regional_NCS_GRP,
San_white_Regional_NCS_GRP,
Venus_Regional_NCS_GRP,
Dove_National_NCS_GRP,
Pears_National_NCS_GRP,
SAVLON_National_NCS_GRP,
SAVLON_Regional_NCS_GRP,
Mysore_Regional_NCS_GRP,
GD_Regional_NCS_GRP,
Nima_National_NCS_GRP,
LIRIL_National_NCS_GRP,
EMPTY_Regional_NCS_GRP,
LIRIL_Regional_NCS_GRP,
SUPERIA_National_NCS_GRP,
GD_National_NCS_GRP,
Margo_National_NCS_GRP,
Vivel_National_NCS_GRP,
Margo_Regional_NCS_GRP,
San_Gly_Regional_NCS_GRP,
MOTI_Regional_NCS_GRP,
San_others_Regional_NCS_GRP,
San_Gly_National_NCS_GRP,
Dyna_Regional_NCS_GRP,
Dyna_National_NCS_GRP,
Nima_Regional_NCS_GRP,
San_white_National_NCS_GRP,
Cin_Regional_NCS_GRP,
HAMAM_Regional_NCS_GRP,
Rex_National_NCS_GRP,
HIMALAYA_NEEM_Regional_NCS_GRP,
Med_Regional_NCS_GRP,
HAMAM_National_NCS_GRP,
Det_Regional_NCS_GRP,
MOTI_National_NCS_GRP,
Mysore_National_NCS_GRP,
JB_NPT_NCS_GRP,
Breeze_NPT_NCS_GRP,
JB_PT_NCS_GRP,
Lux_PT_NCS_GRP,
Breeze_PT_NCS_GRP,
    Breeze_Promo_NCS_GRP
FROM markets_and_neilsenregandmaster a , main_ncs b
WHERE a.period = b.period and a.market = b.market
group by period;
    ERROR 1117 (HY0000): Too many columns
```

This was the exact error i got.
Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: thanks if you provide your query.

Comment: @echo_Me I have added my query, but i have deleted few column names due to space constraints ...

Comment: @echo_Me every markets are in the market column rest are all brands split on some varients .

Answer (score 0):

why are you making every market as column ? you should have column called markets and put there all those markets names instead of making them as columns.

make markets in one column and brands in other column . and you will have just two easy columns :)

so if you add other market , you will add other column ? better you add a value in your markets column.

read [maximum number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410604/maximum-number-of-columns-in-mysql-table)

Comment: i have added all my comments as answer

Comment: all my markets are in one column ..... all columns are required ..so is there any way to join ?